# Use tf.data.Dataset for ppm files

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to use `tf.data.DataSet` with ppm images, but this is not supported out of the box and I am stuck trying to find a possible workaround.

I created a list of images `image_names` that stores the names of all files I'd like to import in the dataset. Following the TensorFlow tutorial, I wrote the following code (for jpeg images):

```py
def parse_function1(filename):
    image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3)

    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)

    return image

# Create a dataset, iterator and print some data
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(image_names)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(image_names))
dataset = dataset.map(parse_function1, num_parallel_calls=1)

iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
init_op = iterator.initializer

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Initialize the iterator
    sess.run(init_op)
    print(sess.run(next_element))
```

This unfortunately does not work with ppm files (there's no `tf.image.decode_ppm`), so I tried to create an alternative parse function that uses imageio to read files from disk:

```py
def parse_function2(filename):
    img_raw = imageio.imread(filename)
    img_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(img_raw, dtype=tf.float32)
    return img_tensor
```

Running the script with `parse_function2` throws an error:

```
File ".local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/imageio/core/request.py", line 240, in _parse_uri
    raise IOError("Cannot understand given URI: %s." % uri_r)
OSError: Cannot understand given URI: <tf.Tensor 'args_0:0' shape=() dtype=string>.
```

My understanding is that the argument `filename` is actually a tensor holding a string value, so I tried to construct the dataset using a `py_function` wrapper. Instead of calling

```py
dataset = dataset.map(parse_function2, num_parallel_calls=1)
```

I do

```py
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x : tf.py_function(parse_function2, [x], Tout=[tf.float32]), num_parallel_calls=1)
```

Now I'm getting an imageio error saying

```
File "/home/martin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/imageio/core/request.py", line 240, in _parse_uri
    raise IOError("Cannot understand given URI: %s." % uri_r)

OSError: Cannot understand given URI: <tf.Tensor: id=21, shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'/home/....
```

Could you please suggest how to solve this. Would you recommend not using `tf.data.Dataset` at all and writing my own class instead? I'm afraid this would never be as efficient as the original `Dataset` class.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
image_raw = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
image = tf.image.decode_image(image_raw)
```

Comment: did you actually try this? decode_image() only works for JPEG, PNG, GIF, and BMP

Comment: @Kai This works for me on TF 1.15. It looks like later versions support PPM. See the "directory" arguments for: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory

Comment: I'm using TF 2.0. I actually wrote a low level TF 2.0 function to do this. It was a good exercise